GPSFAKE: change dates in NMEA frames
We are developing multiple position based applications. We need to test the different scenarios.
We have different test routes in multiple files in NMEA format.
We need to inject the data from these files as if it were GPS (gpsfake) with the real timestamp, not the timestamp of the files.
Is there any way for gpsfake to update the timestamp of NMEA frames?
Thanks in advance
